# Div's height change when float

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a two divs and one of them will be floated to the left(the first one).But I realized that it's height and width change and I don't want that.Where's the problem? Here's my code with js used for floating the div:

```js
function batch() {
  var projects = ["Batch Script Tutorial", "Manage your PC", "Yahoo joke"];
  var text = "";
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < projects.length; i++) {
    text += projects[i] + "<br>";
  }
  document.getElementById("batch").style.float = "left";
  document.getElementById("showbatch").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```css
.project {
  background-color: #5318a0;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px black;
  color: #efedf2;
  font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 5px 7px;
  text-align: left;
}
.project:hover {
  background-color: #8358ba;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px black;
  color: #efedf2;
  font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 5px 7px;
  text-align: left
}
.project:active {
  background-color: #462076;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px white;
  color: #efedf2;
  font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 5px 7px;
  text-align: left
}
```

```html
<div><span class="project" id="batch" onclick="batch()">Projects</span>
</div>
<div id="showbatch" style="display:inline-block"></div>
```

Comment: The height and width don't change - it's location does.  Is this what you're referring to?

Comment: I don't know why but i can't see this effect on this site but you can look at my blog : programming-multilang.tk     page : MS-DOS (the blog is not finished!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<span class="project" id="batch">Projects</span>
<span id="showbatch" style="display:none; vertical-align:top;">
<ul>
    <li>Batch Script Tutorial</li>
    <li>Manage your PC</li>
    <li>Yahoo joke</li>
</ul>
</span>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#batch').click(function(){
  $('#showbatch').css('display', 'inline-block');
})
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zvc9n7pf/)

Comment: It's not a button -it's a div.

Comment: And on my blog (i don't know why) it's height change (my blog is: programming-multilang.tk and the page:MS-DOS Programming)